# Research directions related to the Hilbert-Smith conjecture

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, open-problems, group-actions

The **Hilbert-Smith Conjecture** (HSC) is a famous open problem in geometric group theory stating "for every prime $p$ there are no faithful continuous action of the $p$-adic group of integers $A_p$ on any connected topological $n$-manifold." It is open (afaik) for all dimensions $n > 3$.

> What are some promising directions of research related to the HSC? Specially, what are some realistic (for a beginning grad student) areas of research involving *group actions* of finite groups?

One example related to the HSC may be trying to investigate what properties must a (hypothetical) faithful $A_p$-action satisfy. Is this direction at all promising? (by promising here I mean, can such properties be 'realistically' derivable? I don't mean if this will work towards solving the HSC.) What are some related questions you would suggest someone investigating further involving group actions from this point of view? Any relevant papers/preprints one could look at?

Comment: Where did you see the $p$-adic integers written as $A_p$? That is coming from a quote, so I'd like to see the reference.

Comment: @KConrad: This is not very common I know. Some papers, say, [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.07277) use $A_p$ instead of $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: I see, that paper wants to use $\mathbf Z_p$ in "topologist's notation" to mean the integers mod $p$ rather than the $p$-adic integers.

Comment: The question seems far too broad if it allows things outside HSC (i.e., about groups action in general, even group actions on topological manifolds).

Comment: There seem to be a number of partial results on HSC in arbitrary dimension, but using weakenings of "smoothness" assumptions. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any good survey.

Comment: @YCor: I have edited my question to only include the HSC. This conjecture seems fairly important yet I wonder why there are no recent good survey article on it! I haven't been able to find a "lot" of literature on this either. I believe the conjecture seems promising for an affirmative answer, but yet not so much spotlight on this.